# Cannot convert value of type 'Codable' (aka 'Decodable & Encodable') to expected argument type 'T.Type'

Tags: json, swift, xcode, generics, swift5

I'm working on a small struct that handles the parsing of JSON. Up until now it is all working except I am wanting to pass a custom struct as a structure to use on the decode in `JSONDecoder().decode(type.self, from: data)` but this is throwing the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Codable' (aka 'Decodable & Encodable') to expected argument type 'T.Type'

```
private func parseJson(data: Data, type: Codable) -> Codable? {
    do {
        let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(type.self, from: data)
        
        return decoded
    } catch {
        print("JSON decode error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    return nil
}
```

Is there a way that I can pass a struct into this method to use as the type for the `decode()` function? If I directly set the type I'm trying to pass into the function on the decode() function the code works as expected, it only errors out when I attempt to pass it in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is a generic method:

```
private func parseJson<T: Decodable>(data: Data, type: T.Type) -> T? {
    do {
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(type.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        print("JSON decode error:", error)
        return nil
    }
}
```

You can also omit the type and explicitly set the type of the resulting object:

```
private func parseJson<T: Decodable>(data: Data) -> T? {
    do {
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        print("JSON decode error:", error)
        return nil
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
struct User: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
let user: User = .init(id: 2, name: "abc")
let userData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(user)

let decodedUser: User = parseJson(data: userData)!
decodedUser.name  // "abc"
```

Note:  I am returning optional types but you should definitely make your methods throw and return a non optional as you can see below where I am extending Data:

```
extension Data {
    func decodedObject<T: Decodable>() throws -> T {
        try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: self)
    }
}
```

---

```
do {
    let decodedUser: User = try userData.decodedObject()
    print(decodedUser.name)  // "abc"
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: That seems to be working but I don't really understand how, could you explain it a bit further?

Comment: `Codable` it is not a type it is a protocol. `T` is a generic type that needs to conform to `Decodable`

Comment: The second solution doesn't work for me. It throws `Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function` error.